# How do I get a discord.io message id from a sendMessage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.io

I've set up an event listener for a message. I want to have a bot react to its own message using `bot.addReaction()`. Is there a way to keep the `messageId` after calling it? Something like this:

```
const message = bot.sendMessage({
  to: channelID,
  message: `Oops... Sorry ${user}, that's not something I can understand. 
  After all, I'm just a computer!`,
});

bot.addReaction({
  channelID: channelID,
  messageID: message.d.id,
  reaction: "",
});
```

If not, what's the best way to add a reaction to a bot's own message? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Discord.io is 3 years old. I would recommend using discord.js instead. It's more up-to-date and much easier to use.

Comment: I already switched. I can tell already it's better. The docs are much more instructive and it's just intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the message ID from the `sendMessage()` callback's response object:

```js
const message = bot.sendMessage({
  to: channelID,
  message: `Oops... Sorry ${user}, that's not something I can understand. 
  After all, I'm just a computer!`
}, (err, res) => {
  bot.addReaction({
    channelID,
    messageID: res.id,
    reaction: ""
  });
});
```

**References:**

- [`res.id`](https://github.com/izy521/discord.io/issues/302)

Comment: Thank's @DaemonBeast. I'm new to creating bots, and you've helped a lot.